# Mixing of sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy sessions

Tags: python, session, flask-sqlalchemy

The issue I am having is with the mixing of sqlalchemy sessions with flask-sqlalchemy session. So for context, I am running a flask-restful app on the background and I have a file (runnable.py) with a main method which is supposed to run periodically for an average period of 4 weeks.

This file uses its own session (pure sqlalchemy session) and connects to this app (which uses flask-sqlalchemy session).

After a few hours (sometimes 1 day), I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/runnable.py", line 781, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/runnable.py", line 677, in main
    db_process_attendee(attendee, eid, event_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/runnable.py", line 78, in db_process_attendee
    update_attendee_information(attendee, attributes, eid, event_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/runnable.py", line 117, in update_attendee_information
    update_attendee_profile(attendee, id_attendee_login, eid, event_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/runnable.py", line 291, in update_attendee_profile
    generate_company_tags_lower.generate_company_tags(id_attendee_login)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cron/app/util/generate_company_tags_lower.py", line 28, in generate_company_tags
    filter(a_p.id_attendee_login == id_attendee_login).\
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2426, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2395, in one
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2453, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 436, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 134, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 282, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 767, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 957, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(prelude + sql[:chunk_size-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 916, in _write_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (error(110, 'Connection timed out'))") 'SELECT a_p.id_attendee_profile AS a_p_id_attendee_profile, a_p.id_attendee_login AS a_p_id_attendee_login \nFROM a_p \nWHERE a_p.id_attendee_login = %s' (128368,)
```

I tried the following suggestions but they did not work:

• In my app config, adding "pymysql" to the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
• Doing a db.session.commit() when I enter generate_company_tags(id_attendee_login) before writing a sql select query. I thought it would flush the session.

Btw, the sqlalchemy pool recycle value is set to less than the max in AWS RDS.

Any suggestions on how I can go solving this?

Comment: It would help if you posted the relevant code about how you are creating the session. For example, are you using `flask_scoped_session()` with `sessionmaker()`?

Comment: Yes.
engine = db.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_recycle=3600)
Session = db.scoped_session(db.sessionmaker(bind=engine)).
I am also closing the session after every commit.

Comment: Is your script running an extremely long update or query?

Comment: No. its a few ms to run the SQL query itself. If I run the script, it works perfectly. If I leave it to run around the clock, it faces the MySQL server gone error

Comment: @creavery have you resolved this error?